# Full page scroll and ease on mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel, easing

I'm looking for a jQuery/JavaScript full-page scroll plugin like these: https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify or http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/.

But I also want an 'ease' while scrolling with the mouse wheel (like the trackpad on a mac).

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Best wishes

Comment: Search with smooth-scroll keywords, like this:

https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`onepage-scroll`](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll).

It works like a charm on my websites. Documentations are available there.

Comment: Thank you! What I'm actually looking for is that when the section is higher than 100vh (fe. 200vh) and you scroll in this section that there's an ease on the mouse wheel scroll too. I don't think that's possible with this plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of plugins:

http://www.cssdesignawards.com/articles/15-excellent-jquery-plugins-to-spice-up-your-sites/44/

http://www.learningjquery.com/2015/07/5-easy-jquery-scrolling-plugins-for-one-page-websites

I hope it will help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! What I'm actually looking for is that when the section is higher than 100vh (fe. 200vh) and you scroll in this section that there's an ease on the mouse wheel scroll too.